# What does it say on this coin?

Tags: meaning

[image: coin side 1][image: coin side 2]

I bought this beautiful coin and I have no idea what it says. I think it is Chinese. For the case it is not, please forgive my ignorance, there has been no intention to offend you

Answer (score 10):

獎牌 Medal

農工商部 Ministry of Agriculture, Industry and Commerce

製 make (made)

二等 2nd Class/Grade

[農工商部](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BE%B2%E5%B7%A5%E5%95%86%E9%83%A8)是清朝政府於光緒三十二年（1906年）設立的中央機構。
"Ministry of Agriculture, Industry and Commerce" was the central government established by the Qing government in the thirty-second year during the Guangxu period (1906).

[Price in the August 2013 Hong Kong Auction](http://blog.xuite.net/coins888/twblog/336893504-1907%E5%B9%B4%E5%A4%A7%E6%B8%85%E8%BE%B2%E5%B7%A5%E5%95%86%E9%83%A8%E8%A3%BD%E4%B8%80%E7%AD%89%E3%80%81%E4%BA%8C%E7%AD%89%E5%8F%8A%E4%B8%89%E7%AD%89%E9%8A%80%E8%B3%AA%E7%8D%8E%E7%89%8C%E7%B0%A1%E4%BB%8B%E5%8F%8A%E6%88%90%E4%BA%A4%E5%83%B9)

[農工商部製 二等 獎牌](https://read01.com/EG8kK8.html)

Comment: +1 Definitely a medal from Qing government. There are even Manchu and Mongolian script on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a medal, a prize for second place.

The first picture, on the outside says:

农,工,商,部,制 nóng, gōng,shāng, bù, zhì， basically: Farming, Workers' and Business Department made (by)

In the middle of the first picture it says: 奖牌 jiǎngpái prize, medal

The other side, between the dragons says : 二等 èrděng second prize

It is not money, hope you did not pay too much for it!

Comment: 农,工,商部  better be translated as  'Agriculture, Labor and Commerce departments' here

Comment: also has Manchu text（script derived from Mongolian script)

Answer (score 0):

“农工商部”“奖牌”“二等”It isn't a coin.